# "I would give you all the help you needed" vs. "would need" vs. "need"

Tags: tenses, conditional-perfect

> If you were ever in trouble, I would give you all the help you **needed**.

Can you explain the tense choice for the bolded verb?

How about "all the help you **would need**" or "all the help you **need**"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different conditional clauses — "if you saw", "if you were to see", "if you had seen"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77887/different-conditional-clauses-if-you-saw-if-you-were-to-see-if-you-had)

Comment: There is something about the subjunctive, *If you were, I would...* that calls for *needed*, though I am not the linguist to answer *why*. It doesn't work for me to repeat *would need* and need (a bare infinitive or a second person singular present tense) doesn't sound right to me either. *If you were..., I would give you all you needed (of whatever) is the only option that *sounds* correct to me. :/

Comment: Yes, Indeed , the answer is " needed "

Comment: I know it's about the subjunctive, but why does it call for      " needed " ?

Comment: "I would" is not real, so it has to be matched to subjunctive which is also not real. Read about subjunctive here -> http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is called the 'modal preterite' by the author below. Tense backshifting is a way to denote modality in English.

EG: 'If it rained tomorrow, we'd be out of luck.'
'It's time you went home.' 
'It would be best you left.'

It is closely related to the were-subjunctive, but many researchers don't consider it to be a subjunctive, because it lacks a unique historical form.

Source: Harsh, Wayne. The Subjunctive in English. 1968. p 110.

The English grammar of Quirk, et al. also covers this phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

*...I would give you all the help you **needed/would need/need**.

The first two are grammatical and mean the same thing.

The third is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Why ? could you explain it in more detail  please ?

Comment: Those all seem fine to me (with subtle differences in meaning). Why do you answer the way you did?

Comment: Because the conditional requires the past tense in a subsequent dependent clause. *...If I were rich, I would give you all you WANTED*.

Comment: Thank you ,  then  How about this one ?  ... If you had ever been in trouble, I would have given you all the help you had needed.

Comment: @18yoPolyglot That is alright, except that you don't need the second 'had'. Should be '...all the help you needed'.

Comment: It's quite complicated.  then  how about this one ? ... If you are in trouble, I will give you all the help you will need